# laravel markdown app url

Tags: markdown, laravel-mail

how can I get website url instead of type it in markdown email?

sample:

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'htt://site.co', 'color' => 'green'])
Button
@endcomponent
```

I want instead of typing `http://site.co` have something like `{{$url('/')}}` as we have in blade.

is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

Try 
@component('mail::button', ['url' => '{{route('/')}}', 'color' => 'green'])

it work for me i think it will help you as well

Comment: `A non-numeric value encountered `

Comment: @component('mail::button', ['url' => '{{config('app.url').route('route-name'}}', 'color' => 'green'])      try this

Comment: Try This in your Email Notification may be work public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                   ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
            ->action('Admin Reset Password', url(config('app.url').route('admin.password.reset', $this->token, false)))
            ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
    }

Comment: i'm not using notification i'm using event and listener.  this is all `Mail::to($event->order->user->email)->send(new \App\Mail\UserOrdered($event->order));` and in there action not working